# How to read Cloud Dataflow Job metrics using dataflow api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read the cloud dataflow (java) sink properties especially elements written, to know how many rows are written to the sink. Is there a working example for this? Please provide some pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **job/element_count** metric is the number of elements added to the PCollection, but it is sampled every 60 seconds, and it can specify, through labels, the Job ID and the PCollection. This metric is useful to see how many elements were added to a PCollection in a given minute.

This metric doesn't indicate how many elements are processed in the given minute. For Streaming jobs you can use the **job/total_streaming_data_processed** metric which provides the total bytes of streaming data processed by this Dataflow job. This is sampled every 60 seconds as well.

To know what your job is doing over time, beyond the defined Stackdriver metrics for Dataflow, you can use your own user counters by using the **Metrics class**. The metric shows up as **job/user_counter** with labels for  metric name, job ID and PTransform.

Note that when you define custom metrics in Dataflow, you have to adhere to the [custom metric naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details#label_names). Please also check the documentation for using [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring).